# Windows 8 recovery partition on main hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, partitioning, windows-installation, recovery-partition

I've recently been having a lot of trouble with my current laptop which has caused me to reinstall my operating system several times, and I'm getting sick of always burning installation disks or creating bootable thumb drives. This time, I would like to put the installation image from my Windows 8 disk onto a recovery partition.

I've searched around for the solution but the only things I've found are just for creating thumb drive installers. I've created the partition (12 GB) easily enough but at this point, sadly, I am at a loss.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 has this awesome new feature called **reset mode**, basically it allows you to start from scratch without doing a traditional format. It wipes all the stuff from your PC and leaves you with a clean installation, just as if you had indeed done a format.

This solution is likely to work for you, however from your question the key point is that you dont want to use a disc or USB, unfortunately using reset mode does require some form of installation media. Luckily for you i have written about a work around a while back on the [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/113047/how-to-refresh-or-reset-your-windows-8-pc-without-the-dvd/) website that allows you to use it with no installation media.

If you need to know how to use reset mode or want to know more about it, you can read [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/75901/how-to-use-refresh-and-reset-in-windows-8-to-easily-reinstall-your-pc/).